# Stop opening viewparts windows on eclipse restart

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, swt

I am writing an Eclipse plug-in. My plugin is opening a viewpart window and draw a graph inside. I am running the plug-in and opening the viewpart window and then just closing Eclipse. So What I want is that viewpart window not opened again by default on the next startup of Eclipse. Can anyone tell me how to do that please?

Kind Regards,
Kyriakos

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your [*org.eclipse.ui.views*](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/extension-points/org_eclipse_ui_views.html#e.view) extension set the *restorable* attribute of *view* element to `false`.

```
<extension>
    <view
        ...
        restorable="false">
    </view>
</extension>
```

Comment: Thank you Martti! That save me time!